# How do I merge several Keras models to get a single output without any further training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Here is the code of the simplest cnn model which i trained. Now my Problem is , instead of one model I need to create multiple models (for example 5 models = [model1,model2,..,model5] ) and train the data on those models using loops.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# train your model 
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I have a task where I am asked to train several models and merge all the models to get a single output without any further training.

Comment: I understand that the question is "How do I merge several Keras models to get a single output without any further training?". Could you update the question?

Comment: @rvinas: updated accordingly.